# Creating a matrix in octave

Tags: matrices

I have to make this matrice in octave, using least possible values

```
[ 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
-1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 1 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 1;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0]
```

Your help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
diag(ones(8,1),1)+diag(-ones(8,1),-1)
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much